# Почему не работает bind

Tags: javascript

Почему alert выводит undefined (Firefox)?

```
function f() {
    alert(this._field);
}

function User(name) {
    this._field = name;

    this.func = function () {
       /**/
    };
}

var my_user = new User("Test name");
f.bind(my_user);
f();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что *bind* - **возвращает** новую функцию, а не меняет старую.

```js
function f() {
  alert(this._field);
}

function User(name) {
  this._field = name;

  this.func = function() {
    /**/
  };
}

var my_user = new User("Test name");
var ff = f.bind(my_user);
ff();
```